# How Do I Set Up A Makefile To Build Using Visual-Studio-Style Output Directories?

Tags: c++, linux, build, makefile

I have a basic makefile-based project on Linux.  It also builds in Visual Studio on Windows.

I'd like to modify my Linux makefile to create multiple builds with different binaries, Debug and Release to start, but will probably add others.

How do I set up a Makefile project to build source in different ways to different paths?

For instance, debug build would be something like:

```
g++ -ggdb -Wall -DDEBUG
.o files in ./Debug/obj
.so and binary files in ./Debug/bin
```

And release output would be:

```
g++ -Os -Wall
.o files in ./Release/obj
.so and binary files in ./Release/bin
```

Make debug or make release would make them, or make all would do everything.

I how to create multiple build types in a Makefile, but the part I'm really unclear on is setting output directory and setting which .o file directory to check to see whether source files have been built.

A pointer to relevant examples and docs would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some time for reading, head over to [Paul Smith's homepage](http://make.paulandlesley.org/), who is the maintainer of GNU Make, and read these two articles:

- [How Not to Use VPATH](http://make.paulandlesley.org/vpath.html)
- [Multi-Architecture Builds Using GNU make](http://make.paulandlesley.org/multi-arch.html)

You will then probably understand that it's not a good idea to build in directories other than the current one because it means going against the grain of Make.

The articles will also guide you on how to organise a build, and it might just fit your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have your project support a configuration mechanism (similar to the `./configure` script of Autoconf), such that it can be configured in a directory other than the source directory. Then you can configure and build it in different ways.

Another way is to use the `lndir` tool to create symlinked build trees. This will instantly add multi-build capabilities to just about any project. The idea is that you have a mirror directory tree populated by symlinks to the original files in the original tree. The build system for the program is none the wiser (unless it does idiotic things like canonicalize paths, removing symlinks: maintainers of the Lisp build system ASDF, take note!). It accesses the files through the symlinks, but drops the objects locally. The nice thing is that the source directory can be completel pristine and even read only! And you can do better than a `make clean`: just blow off the `lndir` generated link farm to get to a completely pristine state.

I used tricks like this to build a Linux distro for several architectures (all packages: glibc, gcc, apache, you name it).

It all built from the same working copy; the same unpacked sources.

Hacking this support into the project would be a last resort. If you enjoy the GNU Make language, go for it. Read the Info manual for GNU Make from beginning to end two or three times and off you go ...  I know how, and I have done it that way too, but what's the point. It would take space to explain and isn't worth it.

Comment: The downside to symlinked trees is that although you can edit through the symlinks easily (e.g. fix compile errors via error browsing support in your editor), if you ever add a file, you have to remember to add it in the original tree and refresh the symlinks. It's not a big deal, but a small stone in the shoe can turn into a big nuisance after walking a few miles.